# How to add new UI to cocos2d-x library

Tags: user-interface, cocos2d-x

I have a question about adding new UI widget (in my case its an EditBox but with UIEditView instead of UIEditBox). I make some changes to UIEditBox, named it UIEditView and put into UI folder. Add all the files to the new created group 
Included it in CocosGUI.h, but still can not use it.
[Here the default list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9Dp1.png)
Both Classes in my UIEditView have unique names
[Names of classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgRzy.png)
So what wong? ;(
Thanks in advice

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the entire class, but from what I can see if you just try to access ui::UIEditBox without cocos2d in front of it, it might work. If that's not the case make sure you have NS_CC_BEGIN or using namepace cocos2d in your header and cpp file.

Also you don't have to add your custom ui into the cocos ui folders, unless you want to push it back to to project. Otherwise I have a folder for CustomUI that I host on GitHub as a opensource project so others can use it. Just makes it easier to manage.

If this did not help can you please post more of your files, if you don't mind sharing, will make it easier to help you.

Comment: Solved problem :) It was stupid one. In the begening of the .h file was  "#ifndef __UIEDITTEXT_H__" that is same as original EditBox.h so it was done just once. Changed to "#ifndef __UIEDITTEXTT_H__" and its ok now. Thanks for helping)

Comment: You know you don't have to the guard for multiple header inclusions like that anymore? You can just use #pragma once, any decent C++ compiler will understand that.